# Mixing Java and Kotlin with gradle - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to compile a gradle projet where I have mixed kotlin and java files under src/main/java and src/main/kotlin.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.3.41"
}


ext {
    kotlinVersion = '1.3.41'
}


group 'github.littlechisels'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/kotlin']
    main.resources.srcDirs = []
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlinVersion"
  ...
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.0")
    testRuntime ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.0')
    testImplementation ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.0')
    test.useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

but build\classes\java\main is empty while kotlin one is not

Project builds fine with both IntelliJ and Gradle, but when I run littlechisels.main.Converter  I get a NoClassDefFoundError about java classes :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: littlechisels/main/WorldSave
    at littlechisels.main.Converter.main(Converter.kt:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: littlechisels.main.WorldSave
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Repo can be found here  https://github.com/vinz243/littlechisels

[image]

Comment: Some unknown code run with an unknown command causes an exception with an unknown message and an unknown stack trace. Quite hard to help with that. With 4K+ rep points, you should know [ask].

Comment: I added a few more details

Comment: From the _javadoc_ of class [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html): _Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found._ In other words the classpath for compiling your code is not the same as when you run

Comment: The classpath is the same, littlechisels.main. although build\classes\java\main is empty